# Javascript Custom Function to import JSON formatted YQL query response into Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, yql

Novice Javascript programmer here, maybe bit off more than I can chew.  I am attempting to put JSON formatted data from a YQL query into a Google Drive spreadsheet using a custom function created in Javascript.  I am NOT, repeat NOT, populating a web page, just moving data to a spreadsheet.

Here is the JSON response (as copied from a test function writing it directly to a spreadsheet cell):

> {"query":{"count":1,"created":"2013-08-29T20:56:58Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"optionsChain":{"expiration":"2013-12-21","symbol":"HYS","option":[{"symbol":"HYS131221C00103000","type":"C","strikePrice":"103","lastPrice":"3.00","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"NaN","ask":"5","vol":"2","openInt":"2"},{"symbol":"HYS131221C00105000","type":"C","strikePrice":"105","lastPrice":"0.40","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"NaN","ask":"5","vol":"10","openInt":"11"},{"symbol":"HYS131221C00106000","type":"C","strikePrice":"106","lastPrice":"0.05","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"NaN","ask":"5","vol":"1","openInt":"120"},{"symbol":"HYS131221C00107000","type":"C","strikePrice":"107","lastPrice":"0.10","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"NaN","ask":"0.2","vol":"40","openInt":"80"},{"symbol":"HYS131221P00100000","type":"P","strikePrice":"100","lastPrice":"0.70","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"NaN","ask":"5","vol":"1","openInt":"1"},{"symbol":"HYS131221P00102000","type":"P","strikePrice":"102","lastPrice":"1.00","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"NaN","ask":"5","vol":"15","openInt":"15"},{"symbol":"HYS131221P00103000","type":"P","strikePrice":"103","lastPrice":"1.55","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"NaN","ask":"5","vol":"40","openInt":"50"},{"symbol":"HYS131221P00105000","type":"P","strikePrice":"105","lastPrice":"2.35","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"0.3","ask":"5.2","vol":"15","openInt":"15"},{"symbol":"HYS131221P00107000","type":"P","strikePrice":"107","lastPrice":"6.50","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"2.05","ask":"7","vol":"2","openInt":"20"}]}}}}

Now, if I simply assign the JSON formated object listed above to a variable (i.e. hard code it), I can see the name/value pairs, extract data, do iterations, etc etc.  But when I assign the response directly to a variable (i.e. receiving on the fly) I am unable to see or iterate on anything.  For example, receiving variable "o" can be seen and written to a spreadsheet cell, but it's first child - o["query"] - cannot be seen.  The function initiating the query is located inside of the function using it, so I don't think it is a timing issue.

Comment: Post your custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am answering my own question with a solution I don't completely understand.  Here is the code that works (explanation and further question to follow):

```
function YQLquery() { // A YQL query returning JSONP with XJSON2CSV function embedded in the response
  var fetchstring1 = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"; // constructing YQL query in 4 parts
  var fetchstring2 = "q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.options";
  var fetchstring3 = "%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'HYS'%20AND%20expiration%3D'2013-12'";
  var fetchstring4 = "&format=json&callback=XJSON2CSV&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
  var fetchstring = fetchstring1 + fetchstring2 + fetchstring3 + fetchstring4;  
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchstring); 
  /* This returns (truncated after first option array item, but you get the point):
  XJSON2CSV({"query":{"count":1,"created":"2013-09-13T21:39:35Z","lang":"en-US",
  "results":{"optionsChain":{"expiration":"2013-12-21","symbol":"HYS","option":
  [{"symbol":"HYS131221C00103000","type":"C","strikePrice":"103","lastPrice":
  "3.00","change":"0","changeDir":null,"bid":"1.65","ask":"2","vol":"NaN","openInt":"2"},{ etc etc*/
}//end of function YQLquery

function XJSON2CSV(YQLQueryResponse) { //converts the YQLquery JSONP response payload (i.e. JSON portion) to CSV string
    var vx = YQLQueryResponse;
    var JSONobj = vx["query"]["results"]["optionsChain"]["option"]; // obtain the option array within JSON
    var CSVLine = [];
    var i = 0;
    var j = "";
    for (var i in JSONobj) {
        CSVLine[i] = []; // gets the JSON array objects
        for (var j in JSONobj[i]){
            CSVLine[i].push(JSONobj[i][j]); // get the name/value pairs from each array object
        }; //end of inner loop
    }; //end of outer loop
   return CSVLine; 
} //end of function XJSON2CSV()

function xxx() //test it
{
  return eval(YQLquery().toString());
}
```

Comments:

1) Contrary to what I assumed in the original question, timing WAS the issue.  So I resorted to using a callback function - XJSON2CSV, in this case; having YQL return an invocation of it (with the full JSON string payload as the argument) in the JSONP response.

2) All that worked well to a point - the returned XJSON2CSV invocation was an object and I needed a function.  After quite a bit of experimentation, I obtained a solution by converting it to a string and (against all advice to the contrary) "eval()-"ing it.

Question:  Is there a better way to do that last step (in function "xxx") that doesn't involve "eval()"?  Or, to ask it another way, why can't I just have function xxx "return QYLquery;"

Apologies to Andy for not responding til now.